# Jquery delegate method application

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, delegates

How can I apply the .delegate method to this line of jquery?

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            var color = encodeURI(this.value);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color=' + color, function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);
            });
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Form:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color[]' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
```

PHP receiving colors:

```
$color = $_GET['color'];
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
        $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{ ....
```

I need to allow multiple selections in a checkbox set.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that your current code doesn't solve?  Why are you asking to use `.delegate()`?

Comment: Trying to allow multiselection... currently when selecting a Checkbox I get my first content and then checking another box doesn't combine the results for Box checked 1 and 2... just shows 2

Comment: You'd have to show us the code in your change handler.  That's obviously where the problem is.

Comment: Now that you've given us some idea for what you're really trying to do, I've proposed an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've shown us a little more about what you're really trying to do, you will have to change how your code works and `.delegate()` is not useful for solving that issue.

Right now, you are examining the value of only one checkbox when constructing the URL that you will use with `indexMain.php`.  Instead, you need to examine the values of all the checked checkboxes when constructing that URL.

You don't say how you want to construct the URL when multiple checkboxes are checked, but structurally the code would go something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var colors = [];
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
            colors.push(this.value);
        });
        if (colors.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color=' + colors.join("+"), function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);
            });
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This code will produce a URL for the `.load()` command like this when one or more colors are selected:

```
indexMain.php?color=blue+yellow+green+orange
```

If no colors are selected, it will call `indexMain.php` with no other arguments.

It will be up to your server code to parse the colors from the URL and create the desired response.

Comment: @user1545622 - are you seriously asking that question?  This is a structure for which you have to fill in your own logic for constructing the URL.  You haven't provided us with enough info to know how you want a URL for `indexMain.php` constructed based on the values of multiple checkboxes.  With the information you've provided, this is the most we can offer.  If you EVER want to fully describe the problem you're trying to solve, including the HTML you're using and the URL specification you're trying to generate, we might be able to help more.  Until then, this is what we can do.

Comment: I edited the original post with the additional details, in case you can take a look... thanks!

Comment: @user1545622 - I can't proceed until you show me an example of the  URL to your PHP script when multiple checkboxes are checked.  I don't read PHP so supplying the PHP isn't helping me.  I need to know what the URL is supposed to look like.

Comment: Basically it's a list of multiple items retreived from a SQL table. When a color has been chosen the PHP receives the color and then executes a new SQL query where it filters by that Color. When a new checkbox is checked, another Color should be sent and now the SQL query would be run filtering by 2 Colors.

Comment: @user1545622 - I think the right way to solve this is to examine all the checkboxes each time one is checked and send a URL to your PHP script that has ALL the selected colors in it.  Then you PHP script can do it's job using that list of colors.

Comment: so instead of the IF in your code above I could just do a WHILE? And how could I make it send multiple values? An array?

Comment: In a URL, you can send multiple colors like this: `indexMain.php?color=blue+yellow+green+orange`.

Comment: Well, the question is "how do I send multiple values using a Jquery like the one I posted above"?

Comment: @user1545622 - Is that a question?  My previous comment shows you how to send multiple colors in a URL.

Comment: Thanks, but in your previous comment I see how multiple colors are sent, but it doesn't help me to configure the Jquery so it sends multiple colors. It assumes there is a jquery that is already sending multiple...

Comment: @user1545622 - I assumed you could modify the javascript structure I had in my answer to meet your specific needs.  Since you were unwilling or unable to do that, I've modified the code in my answer one last time to create a URL with multiple colors in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
   // code
});
```

Using jQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** you can do that.

Syntax of `.on()`:

```
$(static_parent).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Where `static_parent` means a non-dynamic container of `target` and `target` is the element to bind event(s).

Answer (score 0):

Delegate can be written as below

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function(){$(this).toggleClass("chosen");});
```

and the same thing can be achieved using latest(available from jquery 1.7) on() like below

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(){$(this).toggleClass("chosen");});
```